# Text Comparing Program

Tags: python, tkinter, glob, txt

I'm making a program where I am supposed to compare text files by returning a list of all the words that come up in the file, and the number of times they come up. I have to disregard a list of words called stopwords so they won't be checked for the number of times they come up. For the first part I need to check if the word is in the stopwords, if it is, i don't count that word, if it isn't in stopwords then I make a brand new row for that word in a dataframe, assuming it doesn't already exist in the data frame, and increment the appearance frequency by 1. Each text file will have a column. I am a little stuck on this part however. I have bits of the code already but I need to fill in the blanks. Here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import glob

import os 
import pandas as pd


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns =["TEXT FILE NAMES HERE..."])
    data_directory = askdirectory(initialdir = "/School_Files/CISC_121/Assignments/Assignment3/Data_Files")
    stopwords = open(os.getcwd() + "/" + "StopWords.txt") 



    text_files = glob.glob(data_directory + "/" + "*.txt")



    for f in text_files:
        infile = open(f, "r", encoding = "UTF-8")
        #now read the file and do all the word-counting etc...
        lines = infile.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            x = 0
            words = line.split()
            while (x < len(words)):
                """
                Check if the word is in the stopwords
                If it isn't, then add the word into a row in a dataframe, for the first occurence, then
                increment the value by 1
                Have a column for each book 
                """
                for line in infile:
                    if word in line:
                        found = True
                        word +=1 
                    else:
                        found = False

                x = x+1

main()
```

If anyone can help me finish this section I'd really appreciate it. Please show the change in code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear @Hypnotix999 it is clear that you are asking others to complete your homework. Perusing your other questions, it is also clear that you haven't bothered to accept some answers from other who have attempted to help you with your assignments. Unsolicited advice: be a little kinder and give back when people help.

Comment: sorry i will do this from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you just want to count the occurrence of the words. For this you could use a dictionary instead of a Dataframe.

And for stopwords, read it to a list.

Try the below code.

```
stopwords = []
count_dictionary {}

with open(os.getcwd() + "/" + "StopWords.txt") as f:
    stopwords = f.read().splitlines()

#your code

while (x < len(words)):
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word in count_dictionary :
            count_dictionary[word] += 1
        else:
            count_dictionary[word] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just saw this and since that time I was able to add something very similar to what you showed me. I really appreciate your time. If you could take a look at my recent post, there have been many changes in my code. This is is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043963/creating-signature-for-text. If you have the time, I'd really appreciate any input!